# Swift: Change the cell's UIButton Image With tableView DidSelect method

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I Have `TableView` with the two label and one `UIButton` inside the Tableview. So on `DidSelect` method i want to change the `UIButton` Image of that particular cell. As attach image.

[image]

Comment: Show your code, what you try?

Comment: do you want to show the button's image as selected?

Comment: Please explain your requirement in more details.

Comment: exactly.. @JarvisTheAvenger

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia do u want to show radio buttons as selected??

Comment: Yes on selecting the cell i want to show the radio button is selected.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia have you created a model for showing list in tableview??

Comment: if you have created a model for it then add one more variable to it named as 'isSelected' and use delegation to tell your view controller that row is selected.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia and in your array of addresses update it after selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check This

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ButtonTblViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var arry = ["Montitanki Chowk","Greenland Chokdi"]
    var SelectData = [NSMutableDictionary]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tbleVw: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0..<arry.count
        {
            self.SelectData.append(["data":arry[i],"isSelect":"NO"])
        }

        self.tbleVw.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // MARK - tableView Delegates

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SelectData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:listTble = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! listTble
        cell.lblTit.text =  self.SelectData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "data") as? String

        cell.btnRdo.tag = indexPath.row
        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(self.sectionTapped(_:)))
        cell.btnRdo.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)

        let selData = self.SelectData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "isSelect") as! NSString

        if selData == "NO" {
            cell.btnRdo.setImage( UIImage(named: "btnUnSel"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell.btnRdo.setImage( UIImage(named: "btnSel"), for: .normal)
        }

        return cell
    }

    @objc func sectionTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if(self.SelectData[(sender.view?.tag)!].value(forKey: "isSelect") as! String == "NO"){
            self.SelectData[(sender.view?.tag)!].setValue("YES", forKey: "isSelect")
        }else{
            self.SelectData[(sender.view?.tag)!].setValue("NO", forKey: "isSelect")
        }
        self.tbleVw.reloadData()
    }

    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

class listTble: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTit: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnRdo: UIButton!
}
```

Out Put

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to first set button tag in `cellForRow` method

after in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you need to set image of button and in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` set unselect image in button.

you can set button image by using :

```
playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let btn = (tableView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! yourCellName).button else {
            return
        }
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourSelectedImage name"), for: .normal)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let btn = (tableView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! yourCellName).button else {
            return
        }
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourNotSelectedImagename"), for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: May I Know why you press the down vote to this answer? It works fine for me.

Comment: I think this is a best way. no need to check any variable.

Comment: The problem with your code is when the user will scroll your selection will vanish.

Comment: we can avoid this scrolling issue with a flag in `cellForRowAt `