# How to save checkmark after using search in SearchBar?

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchbar, checkmark

I am trying to make a search bar in iOS and have made it to where it filters results and then when you click on it, it shows a checkmark. When I delete the search text, the check mark goes away and the full page of cells appears but the cell that I selected in the search is not selected with a check mark. This is implemented in my cell by setSelected method:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    if selected {
        accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

I haven't any logic with checkmark in cellForRowAt and didSelectRowAt methods.

[Here is a GIF of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGort.gif)

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you have two arrays for the tableview?

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301694/swift-change-the-cells-uibutton-image-with-tableview-didselect-method/54303051#54303051

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed no, only one

Comment: Can you show the code for cellForRowAt? If you are reusing table cells in the normal way, you cannot use the cell itself to track things like selected state. Cells which are off screen cease to exist and may get reused to display other data. You really need to keep a separate table to model your data. Set the selected state from the table in ceelForRowAt

Answer (score 1):

I assume all you're currently doing is setting the checkmark on your cell. The cell will be reused and you'll lose the checkmark.

What you need to do is to keep track of the items, e.g. in a `Set`, that the user has checked so far. Upon rendering items in the table view, you'll need to consult this set whether the item is checked. If it is, you'll want to add the checkmark to the cell.

Something along these lines where `Item` is your cell model. This should get you started. You should be able to extend this to a data set with groups for table headers.

```
/// The items that have been checked.
var checkedItems = Set<Item>()

/// All items that are shown when no search has been performed.
var allItems: [Item]

/// The currently displayed items, which is the same as `allItems` in case no
/// search has been performed or a subset of `allItems` in case a search is
/// currently active.
var displayedItems: [Item]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = displayedItems[indexPath.row]
    let cell = // Construct your cell as usual.

    if checkedItems.contains(item) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let item = displayedItems[indexPath.row]

    if checkedItems.contains(item) {
        checkedItems.remove(item)
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        checkedItems.insert(item)
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    displayedItems = // Set the displayed items based on the search text.
    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(.zero, animated: false)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in this way:

```
var selectedCellIndex: String?

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let key = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let values = dictionary[key] {
        selectedCellIndex = values[indexPath.row]
    }
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.tintColor = Color.main()
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let key = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let values = dictionary[key] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = values[indexPath.row]
        if values[indexPath.row] == selectedCellIndex {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```