# UIButton never clicked inside TableviewCell with - did select row at indexpath

Tags: ios, swift

Cant click `UIButton` inside Custom `TableViewCell` , While `TableViewCell` enable -

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

I have one `TableViewController` , and `TableviewCell` class with `StarButton` inside .

When i click anywhere in the cell , i want to push to another `DetailViewController` . 
When i click to the `StarButton` , i want it to change state to .selected

Currently my `UIButton` userInteraction state is enabled

Regardless how many  time i clicked to the `StarButton` , it pushed to the next `DetailViewController` instead. It look like my click passed through the Button .

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
// push to next vc

}
```

While i clicked the `StarButton` ,should be no push to the next VC
When i clicked to other area on the Cell , it should push to next VC

Comment: Can you share your UI? Because one problem might be the way how you placed your button on your `TableViewCell`

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303051/6783598

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Change the cell's UIButton Image With tableView DidSelect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301694/swift-change-the-cells-uibutton-image-with-tableview-didselect-method)

Comment: Put your button inside of Content View of Tableview cell

Comment: Have you make action method of startButton in TableViewCell class ?