# Single selection is not working in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am just changing my Image on `UIButton` When I am tapping on cell . The function is calling but `Image` is not changing . And I want to do `Single Selection`.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! PaymentCell
        cell.btnCheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckTerm"), for: .normal)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! PaymentCell
        cell.btnCheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheckTerm"), for: .normal)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

I just want to change image on cell click with a single selection

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303051/6783598

Comment: @BenRockey I already checked it. but it's too long . Now it's working fine Sh_Khan solved my issue. Thanks for Response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! PaymentCell
```

with

```
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as? PaymentCell else { return }
```

but the better is to change your model to the new image at that indexPath and then reload the tableView to avoid dequeuing problems

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the button selection in your `PaymentCell`:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // get image according to cell selection
    let image = selected ? UIImage(named: "CheckTerm") : UIImage(named: "uncheckTerm")
    // update button image
    btnCheckUnCheck.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a property in view controller which will store the detail of the currently selected index.

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
```

In `cellForRowAt` method of `UITableView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! PaymentCell
            if selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
                cell.btnCheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckTerm"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                cell.btnCheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheckTerm"), for: .normal)
            }
        return cell
    }
```

Change below method as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
```

This will not cause any reloading cells related issues.
Hope this helps.