# How to add Some action on Plus icon swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

I am developing a iPhone application with Local Music and i am using 'MPMediaPickerController' to show local song. but i don't know how to add some functionality on plus icon given below. 
Can someone please explain to me how to create some action on plus icon.

**ScreenShot:**

[image: Below ScreenShot]

Comment: no screenshot present

Comment: Please check...

Comment: check this .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303051/6783598

Comment: What do you actually want? Why you need to add action on built in UI? I guess you want to pick the `mediaItem` then there is a delegate `didPickMediaItems` method which will give you the desired information.

Comment: No i want click on plus icon and add to local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adopting MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate protocol and implementing the following method

```
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, 
    didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want only action on plus icon