# How to add a delete button to Cells on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I'm trying to create an App but I'm struggling with a simple problem: How can I add a delete button to my custom cells?

1. I've created a NewCocoaTouchClass
2. I've created my custom design (added also a button for every cell) and provided the Outlets in the TableViewCellController
3. I managed to implement my custom cell to another viewController
4. I created a button on my viewController

**I'd like that when the user taps on my new button, cell buttons will appear, and then I can delete cells singularly. When I create the IbAction I can't retrieve the cell code because the cell is defined only in my tableViewCode.**

Thank in advance

Ps: I also implemented deleting cells by swipe but my custom cell design is incompatible with the standard rectangular delete option (this is awful).

**TableViewCellController**

```swift
import UIKit

class CustomTableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identificatore = "CustomTableTableViewCell"
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomTableTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ImmagineCella: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TestoCella: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

**ViewController**

```swift
import UIKit

class MaterieViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var materie : [String] = ["zoifvdhfdv", "szvzv", "zdvzfv", "zfdvbfdb", "bfzdfb"]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TableViewMaterie: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        TableViewMaterie.register(CustomTableTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomTableTableViewCell.identificatore)
        
        TableViewMaterie.delegate = self
        TableViewMaterie.dataSource = self
        
        
       
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return materie.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableTableViewCell.identificatore, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableTableViewCell
        cell.TestoCella.text = materie[indexPath.row]
       
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 67.83
    }
    
    @IBAction func EditButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303051/6783598

Comment: you can add button tag in the  cellForAtIndexpath for each button and make delegate , pass the delegate reference from the cellForAtIndexpath method. when the button click time you have to check the button tag and delete the button. in the cell you have to call the delegate , once you delete the button the main class will get know the delete operation through delegates then you have to reload the tableview in the delegate conformance class

Comment: @Jok3r This is almost the worst choice in Swift. A better one is a callback closure to pass the cell and the actual index path back to the controller. This avoids to update all tags by reloading the table view. @ Saucer21 What is wrong with a swipe action?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Comment: @vadian can't we make use of didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @Jok3r What is the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in my project

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String?
{
     return "Delete"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        //Add your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write with add target

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableTableViewCell.identificatore, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableTableViewCell
        cell.TestoCella.text = materie[indexPath.row]
        cell. Button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell. Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonRow = sender.tag
        print(buttonRow)
    }
```